# Why there are little spots during retopology and use subdivison face

Tags: subdivision-surface, retopology

Why there are little spots during retopology and use subdivison face modifier?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Th bottom picture makes me think that there may be some duplicate verts/edges/etc... that are interfering. Try merging by distance (_Select all > M > By distance_). If that doesn't do it, it just may be a matter of the Tri's. Blender likes quads and quads-only, especially on smooth shaded, rounded surfaces, and also especially with Subdivision Modifiers. You may have to find a way to convert it to quads.

Comment: it looks like you have edges on the mirror side? maybe first delete them?